# Failed to ensure ScaledJob is correctly created

Tags: keda

Deploying azure agents on openshift through KEDA scaled job approach. But facing the issue as "**Failed to ensure ScaledJob is correctly created**" from the KEDA

Getting the below issue on openshift activities:

**error parsing azure Pipelines metadata: Get "https://dev.azure.com/fc/_apis/distributedtask/pools?poolName=testing": EOF**

I have checked my configuration files. Those are fine. Please let me know if you have any Idea about the issue